# Compiling Multiple Files with modules

Tags: fortran90

I am programming in Fortran 90 using GFortran and I'm having troubles with Modules. When I compile the code below, I get the following error:

```
Derivatives.f90:7.16:
Included at C:\Users\dchalhub\Dropbox\Doutorado\#Tese\New folder\main.f90:1:
    Use Mesh
            1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'mesh.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
gfortran.exe: Internal error: Aborted (program f951)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
```

So, the 'mesh.mod' file is not created.
But when I remove the first two lines: 'include 'Derivatives.f90'' and 'include 'Poisson.f90'' the module is created without any problems.

After the mod file is created, I put back the first two lines, compile the code again and it works perfectly.

```
include 'Derivatives.f90'
include 'Poisson.f90'

!**************************************************************
MODULE MESH
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: IMAX,JMAX,NMAX
REAL(8), ALLOCATABLE :: XD(:),YD(:),FX(:,:),FY(:,:)
REAL(8) :: PI,E,DX,DY,H,L,RHO,MU
PARAMETER (PI = ACOS(-1.D0))
PARAMETER (E = 2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995)
END MODULE MESH
!**************************************************************



!**************************************************************
!*********** Lid-driven Cavity Program*************************
!**************************************************************
program Cavity
Use Mesh
implicit none


End program Cavity
```

I don't know why but there is something wrong with compiling multiple files with modules.
Does any one know what should I do to make it work properly?

Comment: It appears you have circular references and `Derivatives.f90` has a `USE Mesh` in it. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, I have 'Use Mesh' in Derivatives.f90 and Poisson.f90. Is that a problem?

Comment: Since you are `INCLUDE`ing those files, you don't actually need to compile them in addition -- the source code is literally dropped in place where the `INCLUDE` lines are. What does your build process look like? What files are you compiling and in what order?

Comment: Thank you very much. You are totally right. I just put the include lines after defining the Module Mesh. Thanks again

Comment: I'm glad that helped, but I still think you're doing things wrong... If you are compiling `Derivatives.f90` and `INCLUDE`'ing it, then the build process isn't right and should be altered...

Comment: Actually I'm compiling the main program which is shown above. In the main program I use "Include Derivatives.f90" to include some subroutines that are in "Derivatives.f90".

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Now I'm having trouble with the same issue but using CodeBlocks instead of command line compilation. I posted this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538500/fortran-90-gfortran-and-codeblocks-issue-with-modules-and-multiple-files