# GFortran and CodeBlocks issue with Modules and Multiple Files

Tags: fortran, codeblocks, fortran90, gfortran

I am working with GFortran and CodeBlocks but I'm having an issue about Modules and Multiple files.
i keep getting this error:

```
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'mesh.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

For some reason, GFortran is not building the 'mesh.mod' file.
This problem does not occur when I put all the code in a single .f90 file.

Bellow is an example of code that this error happens.

main.f90

```
MODULE MESH
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: IMAX,JMAX,NMAX
REAL(8), ALLOCATABLE :: XD(:),YD(:),FX(:,:),FY(:,:)
REAL(8) :: PI,E,DX,DY,H,L,RHO,MU
PARAMETER (PI = ACOS(-1.D0))
PARAMETER (E = 2.718)
END MODULE MESH
!**************************************************************

program Cavity
Use Mesh
implicit none
Real(8), Allocatable :: func(:)
Real(8) :: Der,DfDx
integer :: i

IMAX=10
DX=1./10

Allocate(xd(IMAX),func(IMAX))

Do i=1,IMAX
   xd(i)=i*DX
End Do

Do i=1,IMAX
func(i) = xd(i)**2
End Do

Der=Dfdx(func,2)
Write(*,*) Der

End program Cavity
```

Derivatives.f90

```
Real(8) Function DfDx(f,i)
        Use Mesh
        implicit none
        Real(8) :: f(1:Imax)
        integer :: i

           DfDx=(f(i+1)-f(i-1))/(2d0*dx)

        return
end function DfDx
```

When I use console command line compilation instead of CodeBlocks interface I already solved this problem ([Compiling Multiple Files with modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537495/compiling-multiple-files-with-modules)) but I'm still getting this problem with CodeBlocks.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I've never used CodeBlocks, but again I think the issue is compiling things out of order. In what order are you trying to compile the separate files?

Comment: Also, not to sound impolite, but SO doesn't like thanks/signatures/greetings in questions nor does it like having the tag (in this case [tag:fortran90]) in the title. I edited those out of your other question and am about to do the same here

Comment: Ok... Sorry, I didn't know about that. I think you are right, this is probably due to the compiling order but I could not find any options about this in CodeBlocks. Actually, I don't really know what CodeBlocks is doing with the f90 files while compiling. I hope someone could explain it to me.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you there. I use CMake as it has automatic dependency scanning and generation. Hopefully somebody else can help you, I added the [tag:codeblocks] so it will show up for people who follow it.

Comment: Use the generic tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in CodeBlocks "*projects are built in the order of appearence, from top to bottom*" ([CodeBlocks Wiki](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=The_build_process_of_Code%3a%3aBlocks#Using_project_dependencies)), in other words, the files are compiled alphabetically.
Which means that in my case, Derivatives.f90 was being compiled before than Main.f90 causing the error.

A way to circumvent the problem is to set **only** the `Main.f90` file as build target in CodeBlocks:

- Menu `Project/Properties...`
- In `Build Target Files` at the tab `Build targets` check **only** `Main.f90`

And use the command `Include 'File_Name.f90'` inside the `Main.f90` code to include the other `f90` files for compilation in the right order.

Comment: Section 1.11.14 of [the Code::Blocks manual](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/manual_en.pdf) says that you can change the linking order and Section 1.8 says you can use `'Project'-->'Properties'-->'Projects dependencies'` to set that `Derivatives.f90` depends on `Mesh.f90`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming what you have written is how your code is, then it appears that the problem is that the `module mesh` is inside the main program and not a separate file. You should have three files: `Mesh.f90`, `Derivatives.f90` and `Main.f90`.

Mesh.f90 is exactly as you have it,

```
module Mesh
   implicit none
   integer :: IMAX,JMAX,NMAX
   real(8), allocatable :: XD(:),YD(:),FX(:,:),FY(:,:)
   real(8) :: PI,E,DX,DY,H,L,RHO,MU
   parameter (PI = ACOS(-1.D0))
   parameter (E = 2.718)
end module Mesh
```

Derivatives.f90 should be written as another module, using `contains`:

```
module Derivatives
   use mesh
  contains
   real(8) function dfdx(f,i)
      real(8) :: f(i:imax)
      integer :: i

      DfDx=(f(i+1)-f(i-1))/(2d0*dx)

   end function dfdx
end module Derivatives
```

and the Main.f90 will then `use` both modules. Note that I had to eliminate the variable `DfDx`; this is because it conflicts with the `function DfDx` in `module Derivatives`

```
program Cavity
   Use Mesh
   use Derivatives
   implicit none
   Real(8), Allocatable :: func(:)
   Real(8) :: Der
   integer :: i  

   IMAX=10
   DX=1./10

   Allocate(xd(IMAX),func(IMAX))

   Do i=1,IMAX
      xd(i)=i*DX
   End Do

   Do i=1,IMAX
      func(i) = xd(i)**2
   End Do

   Der=Dfdx(func,2)
   Write(*,*) Der

End program Cavity
```

I do not know how CodeBlocks works, but I would presume it lets you choose the compilation order. If that is the case, you should compile Mesh.f90 first, then Derivatives.f90, then compile Main.f90 before linking them to an executable.

When I compiled & linked them, I got an answer of 0.200000002980232; hopefully that links up to what you have as well.

Answer (score 1):

On codeblock, you may go to Project properties > Build targets
Then select the file you want to build first (say mod.f90).
In the "Selected file properties" go to "Build"
Here,change the priority weight. Lower weight implies the file will be built first.