# Fortran .mod file doesn't update when compiling

Tags: module, fortran

I have a very simple Fortran program with some modules inside. I use codeblocks as IDE and gfortran as compiler.

Everytime I change something in a module, for example adding a new parameter constant, the compile procedure won't update the information I added. Even more, if I delete the corresponding .mod file and then rebuild & run, the build log just show 'can't find the corresponding .mod file'. Sometimes this problem doesn't show but sometimes it does. I'm new to Fortran and I'm not sure why. Thanks.

Comment: What does the build log show?

Comment: I had a similar deal with gfortran on a Mac, but when I deleted the file then it regenerated the .mod file. Some compilers look at an environment variable for MODDIR, a -MODDIR=? , or something like that... https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5263/aevog/index.html

Comment: You really must show which commands you are executing, on which files, your error messages and so on... The IDE configuration is essential.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your help. I found my solution in this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538500/gfortran-and-codeblocks-issue-with-modules-and-multiple-files/34723457#34723457     The problem is that codeblocks use a wrong compilation order. By choosing to compile your modules first, you can then use the defined type in other files